# how to get name of a xml tag with js ajax

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I have an xml file i am ripping apart with ajax:

```
<country name="UK">
        <person>
            <name>daniel</name>
            <age>25</city>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>james</name>
            <age>22</city>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>brandy</name>
            <age>16</city>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>nathan</name>
            <age>66</city>
        </person>
    </country>
    <country name="france">
        <person>
            <name>paul</name>
            <age>28</city>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>pierr</name>
            <age>22</city>
        </person>
    </country>
```

Any my JS look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
xmlhttp=null;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
          xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
          var txt="";
          x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");
          for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
            txt=txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
            }
          document.getElementById("myDivName").innerHTML=txt;
          //somehow get the country of that person to write here
          document.getElementById("myDivCountry").innerHTML=txt;

          }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","people.xml",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      }

}
</script>
```

The JS will print the name of the person, but how to i get the name of the country that person belongs to?

this is all example content written for this problem... i didn't right the xml - it's a feed from another location i want to filter

thanks

dan

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parentNode` property to access `country` tag and its attribute name `name` to get its value:

```
var countryNames = "";
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
    countryNames += x[i].parentNode.parentNode.name + "<br />";
}
```